# Magento random product

Tags: magento

Hi I use a script for showing random products on my homepage, but it doesnt show me price. Where is a problem?

http://magentoabid.blogspot.sk/2012/06/display-random-products-from-category.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why that isn't working, but if you want you try some other solutions

1. http://dx3webs.com/front/2010/10/how-to-create-a-random-featured-product-list-on-home-page-in-magento/
2. Update the code above

   Replace the first ~15 lines with:

   ```
   $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
   $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
   Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
   $collection->getSelect()->Limit($this->getNumProducts())->order('rand()');
   $collection->addStoreFilter();
   $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
   //print_r($collection);
   ```

   Replace :

   ```
   <?php for ($i=0; $i < $number_of_products; $i++): ?>
   ```

   with :

   ```
   <?php foreach($collection as $product) :  ?>  //need to end foreach with <?php endforeach; ?>
   ```

   Replace things like this :

   ```
   $displayed_products[$random_products[$i]]->getName();
   ```

   With :

   ```
   $product->getName();
   ```

   (find and replace "$displayed_products[$random_products[$i]]" with "$product")

Comment: Im sorry, but this isnt working for me. I think that I dont do good this changes. Can you change all of this and give me full script. Thank you

Comment: @Patrik... here is  the full script http://pastebin.com/KG8FW5SB (please note, your code above seem to be from an older version of Magento and is not seo friendly)