# Limit number of products displayed in random products block in Magento

Tags: magento, random, count, limit, product

How can the solution provided in [Magento limit the number of products shown with in the new products block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050587/magento-limit-the-number-of-products-shown-with-in-the-new-products-block) be applied to a random products block displayed on the home page?

I currently have the code

```
<reference name="random">
<block type="catalog/product_list_random" name="product_random" template="catalog/product/grid_only.phtml">
 <action method="setProductsCount"><count>3</count></action>
 </block>
    </reference>
```

in my layout update XML. The grid product view default value seems to be dominating this value which is set in the backend System > configuration > catalog > catalog > frontend > "Products per Page on Grid Default Value".

Comment: I'd recommend not to use the built in block for random products at all because it is very unperformant. Read about alternatives here: http://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2015/09/show-random-products-in-magento-you-are-doing-it-wrong/

Answer (score 3):

Take a look @

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/54496/#t224118
- [Magento random product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691674/magento-random-product)
- <strike>http://dx3webs.com/front/2010/10/how-to-create-a-random-featured-product-list-on-home-page-in-magento/</strike>

Also try changing

```
 <action method="setProductsCount"><count>3</count></action>
```

to

```
 <action method="setData"><key>num_products</key><value>[# to display]</value></action>
```

or

```
 <action method="setNumProducts"><num_products>[# to display]</num_products></action>
```

see /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Random.php

```
 $numProducts = $this->getNumProducts() ? $this->getNumProducts() : 0;
```

You could also try adding this to your cms page

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list_random" category_id="YOUR_CATEGORY_ID" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" column_count="4" num_products="12"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your grid_only.phtml file you should write following code to get random products, here limit you can pass as you want, here i have giving category wise random product code.

```
$categoryid = 15;
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($categoryid);
$products = $category->getProductCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$products->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
$products->getSelect()->limit(4);
foreach($products as $prod)
{
  echo $prod->getName() ."<br>";
  $img=$prod->getSmallImageUrl();
  echo "<img src='$img'>" ."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer these link http://blog.magikcommerce.com/random-products-magento-home-page/

hope this will help you.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can get latest products in magento with the following code:

```
<?php
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
//Magento does not load all attributes by default
//Add as many as you like
$products->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$products->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
$products->getSelect()->limit(22);
foreach($products as $product) {

echo '<a href="'.$product->getProductUrl().'">'.$product->name.'</a> - ';     
}
```

Taken from [here](http://wpressthemess.com/2013/10/26/get-latest-product-magento/)